# How to generate file with name yyyyMMdd.2.log with log4net

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

Here is the appender I used in `app.config`, it will generate files like `20120501.log.1`, while what I expected is `20120501.1.log`.

```xml
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
  <file value="logs\" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMddt'.log.'" />
  <countDirection value="1" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
  <maximumFileSize value="1000kb" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 7):

This functionality is part of version 1.2.11. There is a new setting for the rolling file appender:

```
<preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
```

Here is the link to the JIRA issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-64

Answer (score -1):

In order to do this first you need to set your config file:

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net"> 
     <File type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="App_Data/%property{LogName}" /> 
     ...
</appender>
```

Then in your Global.asax file you set your LogName details:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Global.asax"); 
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{ 
    // Set logfile name and application name variables 
    log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = String.Format("{0}.2.log",DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
    ...
}
```

Comment: this does not make much sense: it is not about an initial file name, it is about names of rolled files. It also seems that the OP does not have a web application (so there is no Global.asax)